# How can I check if a SKSpriteNode that has been touched also of some other type that inherits from SKSpriteNode?

Tags: class, types, sprite-kit, touch

I need to check which of my custom - class SKSpriteNode inherited objects is touched. I have some elements in my game like:

```
@interface Hero : SKSpriteNode
```

and a non playing character element:

```
@interface StaticLevelElement : SKSpriteNode
```

and I need to check which one has been touched and to invoke the proper method accordingly (either the method form the Hero or from the StaticLevelElement class).

Which method could I use to differentiate between the specific types of classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
if ([node isKindOfClass:[StaticLevelElement class]]){
     NSLog(@"Touched node is StaticLevelElement");

}else if([node isKindOfClass:[Hero class]]){
    NSLog(@"Touched node is Hero");
}
```

From the docs about `isKindOfClass`: method:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an
>   instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from
>   that class.

Look at this part:

> ...or an instance of any class that inherits from that class

You should be careful, because if you subclass `StaticLevelElement` like this:

```
@interface SubclassOfStaticLevelElement : StaticLevelElement

@end
```

And inside touchesBegan do this:

```
if ([node isKindOfClass:[StaticLevelElement class]]){

     NSLog(@"Touched node is StaticLevelElement");
}
```

The method will return true if you touch both, instances of `StaticLevelElement` and instances of `SubclassOfStaticLevelElement`. This is because `SubclassOfStaticLevelElement` inherits from `StaticLevelElement`.

So I guess, this is not the optimal method for you. In SpriteKit, in situations like yours, people often use the method below (by setting the `SKNode's` [name](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/name) property).

Inside your `Hero's` initializer (or you can name your nodes upon creation inside your scene):

```
self.name = @"hero";
```

Then in your `touchesBegan`:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"]){
    NSLog(@"Touched node is hero");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just override the `touchesBegan` method inside of your SKSpriteNode sub classes, and execute their functions accordingly.  This leaves the least amount of change for error, because this method will only be called when the system has determined that the particular node has been touched.

If you need to call some kind of method from the main scene, you could then use `NSNotificationCenter` to send a message to the scene (This will also work if you need to communicate with many different objects,) you could call the scene methods by having the hero have a property that stores the instance of the scene, or you could have a property called isTouched, which you set to true (Yes) when you are in `touchesBegan` and false (No) when you are in `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`, along with some kind of identification property to eliminate the need to do extensive searching, and pretty much do a call like

```
  if(node.isTouched && node.identifier == "StaticLevelElement")
  {
       //do stuff pertaining to StaticLevelElement 
  }
```